# Get All Values of Document Fields Without The Need For The Field Name

Tags: ios, swift, variables, google-cloud-firestore

In swift I have the following array:

```
var postalCode = [String]()
```

in Firestore I will have many documents in the future with many fields in each that will include postalCodes. Something like this:

[image]

Now, how can I get the values of all documents in my collection (collection is called deliveryPostalCodes) regardless of the name of the field? Because in the future I will have to add many fields in here and I can estimate how many documents and fields I will create and what their names would be. So I want to get only the values which in this example would be something like `M8V` and store it in my variable `var postalCode = [String]()`. I have the following code; but in this I have to call out what field name should be (code1):

```
db.collection(DatabaseRef.deliveryPostalCodes).getDocuments { (snap, error) in
            if let error = error{
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            snap?.documents.forEach({ (doc) in
                 let code1 = doc[DatabaseRef.code1] as? String ?? ""
   })
}
```

how can I do this without calling the field name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all fields in the document by calling its [`DocumentSnapshot.data()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentSnapshot#data), which returns a `[String: Any]`. After that, you can get just get the values from the map (dropping the keys), and then filter the resulting array to remove the empty values.

It would look something like this:

```
snap?.documents.forEach({ (doc) in
  let data = doc.data()
  let nonEmptyValues = (Array(data.values) as! [String]).filter { !$0.isEmpty }
  ...
})
```

---

I always find it easiest to test this type of thing in an online playground, such as http://online.swiftplayground.run/. My test bed for this answer:

```
import Foundation

let data:[String:Any] = ["key1": "value1", "key2": "42", "key3": "", "key4": "value4"]

print(data)
print(data.values)
print((Array(data.values) as! [String]).filter { !$0.isEmpty })
```

Which prints:

> ["key3": "", "key2": "42", "key1": "value1", "key4": "value4"]
>
> ["", "42", "value1", "value4"]
>
> ["42", "value1", "value4"]

Comment: I get this error: `Value of type 'Any' has no member 'isEmpty'` do you know why?

Comment: Also when I try to append to the array `postalCode.append(nonEmptyValues)` it gives me this error: `Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected argument type 'String'`

Comment: Good one, I forgot to convert the values to a `[String]`. I updated my answer with the correct code, tested in http://online.swiftplayground.run

Comment: So that worked for the first error. But when Im trying to append `postalCode.append(nonEmptyValues)` it is still giving be this error `Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'`

Comment: I changed my append to this and it worked: `postalCode.append(contentsOf: nonEmptyValues)`

Comment: Do you know how I can do this line if Im already in the document? So my query would be this instead `db.collection(DatabaseRef.deliveryPostalCodes).Document().getDocument` now how would I change this line of code? `let nonEmptyValues = (Array(data.values) as! [String]).filter { !$0.isEmpty }` since Im in a specific document.

Comment: That lines stays the same, but your document in that case comes from an `onSuccessListener`. See the examples here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data